# Проблема в FF при наведении на строку таблицы

Tags: html, css

При наведении на строку таблицы она должна выделяться красной 2px рамкой.
Везде все хорошо показывает, а в FF правый нижний и левый нижний уголки не показываются (обрезаются)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за чего может быть?

Проверил в Хром, Опера, Сафари, ИЕ такого нет.

[Код на jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnef1084/)

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table > tbody > tr {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}

table > tbody > tr > td {
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
}

table tr:hover {
    border-left: 2px solid #C0504E;
    border-right: 2px solid #C0504E;
    cursor: pointer;
}

table tr:hover td {
    border-top: 2px solid #C0504E;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #C0504E;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Еще вопрос: почему для последней ячейки не надо писать следующее

```
table > tbody > tr > td:last-child { border-right: none; }
```

Comment: Правильнее было бы так  `table tr:hover {border: 2px solid #C0504E;}`, а 
`table tr:hover td {    cursor: pointer; }`

Comment: А вы в jsfiddle пробовали так как написали выше? Я тоже поначалу делал как вы написали, но верхние строки не показываются при наведении. Причем не только в FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `outline` вместо `border`.

```
table tr:hover {
    outline: 2px solid #C0504E;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

`table tr:hover td` удаляйте.

*outline* в отличие от *border* не занимает места, поэтому не требуется везде ставить одинаковую ширину рамки, чтобы контент "не прыгал" при наведении мышкой.

Дополнительный плюс в том, что не остаются незакрашенными вертикальные серые линии.

https://jsfiddle.net/0dev/nnef1084/4/

Ссылки по теме:

1. https://webref.ru/css/outline
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline

Answer (score 1):

Тестируйте:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table > tbody > tr > td {
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

table > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
}

table > tbody > tr > td:last-child {
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
}

table > tbody > tr > td {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}

table > tbody > tr:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

table > tbody > tr:hover > td {
  border-top: 2px solid #C0504E;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #C0504E;
}

table > tbody > tr:hover > td:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid #C0504E;
}

table > tbody > tr:hover > td:last-child {
  border-right: 2px solid #C0504E;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Интересный вариант, хоть и громоздкий